# PyFirmata digital input receives None while working well on debug

Tags: python, arduino, firmata

I'm studying pyFirmata protocol with some examples. As an exercise I'm doing PIR sensor system. When I'm running the code pyFirmata always outputs 'None' value. However if I'm doing debugging in PyCharm everything works as it should be. On Arduino the StandardFirmata sketch is uploaded. Anyone knows what is the cause of this behaviour?

The code:

```
import pyfirmata
from time import sleep

def blinkled(pin, message):
    print(message)
    board.digital[pin].write(1)
    sleep(1)
    board.digital[pin].write(0)
    sleep(1)


port = '/dev/cu.usbmodem1411'
board = pyfirmata.Arduino(port)

it = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(board)
it.start()

pirPin = board.get_pin('d:7:i')
redPin = 12
greenPin = 13

while True:
    value = pirPin.read()
    while value is None:
        print("None")
        sleep(1)
        pass

    if value is True:
        blinkled(redPin, "Motion Detected.")

    else:
        blinkled(greenPin, "No Motion Detected.")

board.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found that "while" statement should be replaced by "if". Then everything working. Do not understand this behaviour.

1. Why program stuck with "while" on receiving None?
2. Why in debug mode everything is fine?

I will appreciate if anyone can explain.

The code resolved this issue:

```
if value is None:
    print("None")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to switching to the if clause as OP pointed out, a **continue statement** should be used to *continue at the top of the loop*:

```
if value is None:
    print("None")
    continue
```

This would result in the code logic not running through the additional clauses after it fails the initial "None value" test.